# How to get UserName of Twitter user after login with Firebase. ANDROID

Tags: java, android, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am authenticating the user with Firebase using their Twitter account. But I don't know how can I get the `UserName`.

Here is my code. I have tried everything...

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);



        //mAuth.getAccessToken()
        //AuthResult rs = FirebaseAuth;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
         user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

          AuthResult rs = (AuthResult) response.getCredentialForLinking();
          String uno =  rs.getAdditionalUserInfo().getUsername();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uno,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



         //  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity_tapeo.class);
           // startActivity(i);

            // ...
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.getError().getErrorCode()+" "+ response.getError().getErrorCode(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
            // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
            // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
            // ...
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Have you tried getDisplayName?

Comment: What is the excact problem. You just not get username ? Can you pass these 2 lines
if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) { 
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

Comment: Yes, that brings me the name of the profile account, not the @username that is what i am looking for

Comment: I think you won't be able to get a Username. Here is what Firebase documentation says https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo.html

Comment: If you have additional information, add that to your original question please.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get the user name of a Twitter account from the `FirebaseUser` object, using the following lines of code:

```
Firebaseuser firebaseuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String displayName = firebaseuser.getDisplayName(); //Is not possible
```

`FirebaseUser` object doesn't provide such information. However, you can still get the user name but using AdditionalUserInfo's [getUsername()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#getUsername()) method:

> Returns the username if the provider is GitHub or Twitter.

To see how it looks like in code, please check the official documentation regarding on how to [handle the sign-in flow with the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk), where you'll find a working example.

See, you have to call [getPendingAuthResult()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getPendingAuthResult()):

```
firebaseAuth.getAdditionalUserInfo();
```

In order to be able to get the user name.